# Optimize retrieval of data from a dictionary dataset

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

I am using a dataset structured as following:

```
{
"TableName": "T60300C",
"SeriesCode": "B4186C",
"LineNumber": "86",
"LineDescription": "Government enterprises",
"TimePeriod": "1999",
"METRIC_NAME": "Current Dollars",
"CL_UNIT": "Level",
"UNIT_MULT": "6",
"DataValue": "38,275",
"NoteRef": "T60300C,T60300C.1"
},
{
"TableName": "T60300C",
"SeriesCode": "B4186C",
"LineNumber": "86",
"LineDescription": "Government enterprises",
"TimePeriod": "2000",
"METRIC_NAME": "Current Dollars",
"CL_UNIT": "Level",
"UNIT_MULT": "6",
"DataValue": "40,810",
"NoteRef": "T60300C,T60300C.1"
},
```

Here's another section (same thing just showing what changes)

```
{
"TableName": "T60300C",
"SeriesCode": "A4183C",
"LineNumber": "83",
"LineDescription": "General government",
"TimePeriod": "2000",
"METRIC_NAME": "Current Dollars",
"CL_UNIT": "Level",
"UNIT_MULT": "6",
"DataValue": "543,989",
"NoteRef": "T60300C"
},
```

As you can see the LineDescription occurs as many times as there are entries for it, Series Code and Line Numbers are identifiers for the LineDescription and TableName remains the same.

I would like to restructure this information for easier processing into a dataframe. Since all of the entries correspond to the same subject matter, I wish to create a dictionary as follows:

```
dataEntries = {}
dataEntries['T60300C'] = {'B4186C':[(DataValue,TimePeriod),(DataValue,TimePeriod), (etc.) ], 'A4183C':[(DataValue,TimePeriod),(DataValue,TimePeriod), (etc.)], etc.}
```

Right now I'm iterating through the whole dataset and adding the data using an if statement (in a for loop, from a set of unique SeriesCodes).

```
tupe = tuple()
listoftupes = list()
for uniqueSeriesCode in datasetSeriesCodes:
     if dataset['SeriesCode'] == uniqueSeriesCode:
         tupe = (dataset['DataValue'],dataset['TimePeriod'])
         listoftupes.append(tupe)
```

My question is:
Is this the fastest (most performant) way to traverse the dataset? Is there a better way? This is a very large dataset.

Comment: Are you sure the example code is correct? It seems strange to add the same constant tuple in the list when an item is equal.

Comment: @JérômeRichard thank you for your reply- when I implemented this instead of adding 'tupe' to the list I just wrote ```listoftupes.append((dataset['DataValue'],dataset['TimePeriod))``` is that what you are referring to?

Comment: I wanted to point out that `tupe` is a constant in the loop and so the same value is added multiple time which is suspicious.